# ReceiveSecurityFilter does not contain a constructor that takes 0 arguments

Tags: c#, web-services, soap

So I am trying to [create a custom policy assertion that secures SOAP messages](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa528788.aspx) in C# (Visual Studio 2015), and I fail on the first step, code looks like this:

```
using Microsoft.Web.Services3;
using Microsoft.Web.Services3.Security;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    class CustomSecurityServerInputFilter : ReceiveSecurityFilter
    {
        public override void ValidateMessageSecurity(SoapEnvelope envelope, Security security)
        {
        }
    }
}
```

And I get error [CS1729](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384029.aspx):

> '[ReceiveSecurityFilter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.web.services3.security.receivesecurityfilter.aspx)' does not contain a constructor that takes 0 arguments

And I have no idea what to do now...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've got an answer on Microsoft [forum](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/b73ecbda-ae87-46a9-9444-43e9c8d4f301/receivesecurityfilter-does-not-contain-a-constructor-that-takes-0-arguments):

```
using Microsoft.Web.Services3;
using Microsoft.Web.Services3.Security;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    class CustomSecurityServerInputFilter : ReceiveSecurityFilter
    {
        public override void ValidateMessageSecurity(SoapEnvelope envelope, Security security)
        {
            // do stuff
        }
        public CustomSecurityServerInputFilter(string serviceActor, bool isClient) : base(serviceActor, isClient)
        { }
    }
}
```